# How to create adTagUrl in Google Adsense account?

Tags: adsense

I am working with Google Flash IMA ads Flash version 3.0. This new update seems very less parameters for requesting an ad from Google AdSense. Ex,

```
        var adsRequestDFP:AdsRequest = new AdsRequest();
        adsRequestDFP.linearAdSlotWidth = 400;
        adsRequestDFP.linearAdSlotHeight = 300;
        adsRequestDFP.nonLinearAdSlotWidth = 400;
        adsRequestDFP.nonLinearAdSlotHeight = 300;
        adsRequestDFP.adTagUrl = "http://ad.doubleclick.net/pfadx/AngelaSite;kw=html5linearnonlinear;sz=300x300;ord=5036130;dcmt=text/xml"
```

Here my problem is with the adTagUrl. I just used the sample URL and have finished the work. But now I want to make it work with my ads, but I have no clue about how to create one adTagURL so that my ads will be invoked randomly in my flash ad container.